# Concatenate with pipe char but remove trailing pipes (expressions only)

Tags: sql, oracle

Specifically, I am using REGEXP_REPLACE, which works out perfectly if I'm using commas. But if I replaced commas with pipes (|), the following code does not remove any trailing pipes. Any idea why?

Code using Comma:

```
 select username,
  regexp_replace (
   (case when clan is not null then clan ||', ' END) ||
   (case when job is not null then job ||', ' END) ||       
   (case when level is not null then level END), ', $',' ') desc      
 from dominions;
```

Correct Output using Comma:

```
 USERNAME       DESC
 benedict       rage, hunter, 89
 jamilah        wizard, 42
 anne           happy_elfs, elven
 tommy          19
```

Code using Pipe:

```
 select username,
  regexp_replace (
   (case when clan is not null then clan ||' | ' END) ||
   (case when job is not null then job ||' | ' END) ||       
   (case when level is not null then level END), '| $',' ') desc      
 from dominions;
```

Wrong Output using Pipe:

```
 USERNAME       DESC
 benedict       rage | hunter | 89 |
 jamilah        wizard | 42 |
 anne           happy_elfs | elven |
 tommy          19 |
```

If the above code cannot be corrected, any other solution using expressions?

Comment: Your spacing is not the same in your delimiters: `', '` vs `' | '`,  but in your regex you used `'| $'` and not `' | $'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEVEL` and `DESC` are both reserved words; you cannot use them as an unquoted identifiers and would have to use quoted identifiers (and you probably should use a different identifier instead of using a quoted identifier).

`|` has special meaning in regular expressions as `OR`. If you want to use it as the character then you need to escape it using `\|`:

```sql
SELECT username,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         CASE WHEN clan    IS NOT NULL THEN clan ||' | ' END ||
         CASE WHEN job     IS NOT NULL THEN job ||' | ' END ||       
         CASE WHEN "LEVEL" IS NOT NULL THEN "LEVEL" END,
         ' \| $'
       ) AS description
FROM   dominions;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dominions (username, clan, job, "LEVEL") AS
 SELECT 'benedict', 'rage',       'hunter', 89   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'jamilah',  NULL,         'wizard', 42   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'anne',     'happy_elfs', 'elven',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'tommy',    NULL,         NULL,     19   FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| USERNAME | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| benedict | rage | hunter | 89 |
| jamilah | wizard | 42 |
| anne | happy_elfs | elven |
| tommy | 19 |

---

Regular expressions are slow, it may be more to type but you could use simple string functions instead:

```sql
SELECT username,
       REPLACE(
         TRIM(
           TRAILING '|' FROM
           CASE WHEN clan    IS NOT NULL THEN clan ||'|' END ||
           CASE WHEN job     IS NOT NULL THEN job ||'|' END ||       
           CASE WHEN "LEVEL" IS NOT NULL THEN "LEVEL" END
         ),
         '|',
         ' | '
       ) AS description
FROM   dominions;
```

or generate the string so you do not have to remove trailing delimiters:

```sql
SELECT username,
       CASE
       WHEN clan IS NOT NULL
       THEN clan || CASE WHEN job IS NOT NULL OR "LEVEL" IS NOT NULL THEN ' | ' END
       END
       ||
       CASE
       WHEN job IS NOT NULL
       THEN job || CASE WHEN "LEVEL" IS NOT NULL THEN ' | ' END
       END
       ||
       CASE WHEN "LEVEL" IS NOT NULL THEN "LEVEL" END
         AS description
FROM   dominions;
```

Which both output the same as the first query.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lsanh7AF)

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, I figured they were reserved words when they turned blue lol - I'll change them. And yes, simply escaping it worked perfectly! I could've use case statement but for some reason I find expressions cleaner, but didn't consider performance, so I might use that instead. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

If you were using code such as php you could maybe perform a check for the last element but as you are trying to do this purely in SQL I would suggest having the last command add a null value or empty string on the end to avoid any error. Please note that this is a theoretical solution as I don't know which SQL version you are using, if you are using it in conjunction with any other programming language you could use if/then to detect the last item in the sequence. I'm sure someone may have a better answer for this eventually.